# TLS получаю ошибку x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: golang, tcp, tls, x509

Генерирую каждый раз новый сертификат с уникальным серийным номером при запуске сервера сроком на 12 часов, но при попытке подключиться со cтороны клиента получаю `x509: certificate signed by unknown authority.` Искал возможное решение проблемы на просторах интернета, но ничего внятного не нашел и не понимаю как решить эту проблему

Вот код сервера:

```go
func main() {
    key, err := rsa.GenerateKey(rand.Reader, 2048)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    serialNumber, err := rand.Int(rand.Reader, new(big.Int).Lsh(big.NewInt(1), 128))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    x509templ := x509.Certificate{
        NotBefore:    time.Now(),
        NotAfter:     time.Now().Add(time.Hour * 12),
        IsCA:         true,
        SerialNumber: serialNumber,
        Subject: pkix.Name{
            Organization: []string{"Acme Co"},
        },
        BasicConstraintsValid: true,
        ExtKeyUsage:           []x509.ExtKeyUsage{x509.ExtKeyUsageServerAuth},
    }

    cert, err := x509.CreateCertificate(rand.Reader, &x509templ, &x509templ, &key.PublicKey, key)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    keyPem := pem.EncodeToMemory(&pem.Block{Type: "RSA PRIVATE KEY", Bytes: x509.MarshalPKCS1PrivateKey(key)})
    certPem := pem.EncodeToMemory(&pem.Block{Type: "CERTIFICATE", Bytes: cert})
    tlsCert, err := tls.X509KeyPair(certPem, keyPem)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    l, err := tls.Listen("tcp", addr, &tls.Config{Certificates: []tls.Certificate{*tlsCert}})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    defer l.Close()
    fmt.Println("Starting listening...")
    for {
        fd, err := l.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }

        conn := &Conn{fd: fd, closed: false}
        go handleConn(conn)
    }

}
```

Код клиента:

```go
func main() {
    conn, err := tls.Dial("tcp", "localhost:19000", &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: false})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

}
```

Comment: "после перезапуск сервера должен идти и проходить новая генерация сертификата" а где это должно? пример вашего кода это не должен делать

Comment: @SeniorPomidor это не полный код, обновил код и описание. Имеется ввиду что каждый раз когда я запускаю сервер генерируется новый уникальный серийный номер для сертификата. Но проблема не в этом, а в том что даже при первичном запуске клиент получает эту ошибку

Comment: Очевидно, вы не являетесь доверенным корневым центром сертификации, а значит никакой клиент никогда не будет доверять вашим сгенерированным сертификатам

Comment: @andreymal мне нужно получать сертификат к примеру у Lets Encrypt? Я вообще TLS выбрал в качестве гибридной криптографии, чтобы не писать свои костыли которые скорее всего будут уступать по безопасности без знания тонких нюансов. Я хочу автоматически генерировать сертификаты в любое угодное мне время, использовать TLS как транспортный уровень для собственного протокола

Comment: @Mothership по-хорошему нужен Let's Encrypt, ага. По-плохому вы можете добавить свой собственный корневой сертификат в доверенные в настройках всей ОС или конкретно своего приложения ([tls.Config.RootCAs](https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/tls#Config) видимо) или спросить пользователя, доверяет ли он текущему сертификату (не в курсе как это сделать в golang)